# Visual Paradigm Data Flow Diagrams

Tags: visual-paradigm, dataflow-diagram

Am trying to design a Data Flow Diagram for a system using Visual Paradigm Community Edition on Ubuntu 14.04 but can't seem to find Data Flow Diagram in the list of diagrams, any clue why since according to visual paradigm website, there should be a data flow diagram in the list of diagrams??

Comment: I believe Data flow diagram does not included in the Visual Paradigm Community. See Feature List Comparison between [Visual Paradigm modeler vs community Edition](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/solution/freeumltool/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16664460)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data Flow Diagram is available in the Modeler (and any higher) Edition of Visual Paradigm. Since you are using the Community Edition, which is an edition below the Modeler Edition, you cannot create Data Flow Diagram there.

If you meant to evaluate this feature, try with their evaluation version instead. You can download it from their download page:
https://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it in version 14.0, Modeller edition.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is worth mentionning that the Data Flow Diagram is only available in Visual Paradigm from version 14 (as well as many other diagrams). You said you had Ubuntu 14.04 but in this case, only Visual Paradigm's version matters.

As shown as Pétur Ingi Egilsson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41537511/5771029) you can access it from the File menu but also in the standard list shown when doing `Diagrams > New`.